# Return value when three conditions are met in an row

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

```
System   DB    Type  Result
  1      DB1    Q1
  1      DB1    Q2
  1      DB2    Q1
  1      DB2    Q1
```

I would like a formula that returns a 1 in the 'Result' column if any other row has the same system ID, the same DB ID but a different ID in the Type column. Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,"<>" & C2),1,"")
```

[image]